# How to deal with extended(280 characters) Tweets using twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Recently **twitter** has expanded the character limit of a tweet to **280 characters**.
Since then, the **TwitteR** package **only** retrieves (or shows, IDK) the initial **140** characters of an extended tweet.

```
# load package
library(twitteR)

# set oauth
 setup_twitter_oauth(Consumer_Key,Consumer_Secret,Access_Token,Access_Token_Secret)

# get user timeline
k<-userTimeline("SenateFloor", n = 50, includeRts = T)

# to data frame
k<-twListToDF(k)

# print tweet text
print(k$text[1:5])
```

Console output

```
[1] "#Senate in at 4:00 PM. Following Leader remarks, will proceed to Executive Session &amp; resume consideration of Cal. #… https:// t.co/BpcPa15Twp"

[2] "RT @GovTop: Weekly Digest of the #CongressionalRecord https:// t.co/vuH71y8FpH"   

[3] "#HJRes123 ( Making further continuing appropriations for fiscal year 2018). The Joint Resolution was agreed to by a… https:// t.co/bquyMPPhhm"

[4] "#HJRes123 ( Making further continuing appropriations for fiscal year 2018). https:// t.co/SOmYJ3Dv4t" 

[5] "Cal. #167, Susan Bodine to be Assistant Administrator of the Environmental Protection Agency. The nomination was co… https:// t.co/pW7qphwloh"
```

As you can see, an elipsis (...) cuts the tweets that pass the 140 limit.

```
> nchar(k2$text[1:5])
[1] 144  77 140  99 140
```

**Is there any way to get the whole text from this extended tweets?**

Comment: Use [`rtweet`](http://rtweet.info/). It's simpler, faster and the author is super responsive to questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comment, just use `rtweet`:

```
library(rtweet)
library(tidyverse)

sen_df <- get_timeline("SenateFloor", 300)

mutate(sen_df, `Tweet Length`=map_dbl(text, nchar)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(`Tweet Length`)) +
  ggalt::geom_bkde(color="steelblue", fill="steelblue", alpha=2/3) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  labs(title="@SenateFloor Tweet Length Distribution") +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum_rc(grid="XY")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to continue to use twitteR then you could try this:

```
# get user timeline
k<-userTimeline("SenateFloor", n = 50, includeRts = T, tweet_mode = "extended")
```